# I think my sqlite delete function in android leaves rows filled with null

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try to open an `Activity` in my Android app it shuts down with:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

My code in Activity that fails to run:

```
TVShowsDB db = new TVShowsDB(this);
    List<TVShow> shows = db.getAllShows();

    List<String> showTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (TVShow show : shows) {
        showTitles.add(show.getName());
    } 

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.Row, showTitles);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Activity run well just before I used my delete function for the first time:

```
public void deleteShow(String title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SHOWS, KEY_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] { title });
    db.close();
}
```

Tried to find what could cause this happen and added print statement:

```
for(TVShow show : shows) {
        System.out.println(show.getName());
        System.out.println(show.getAirdate());
    }
```

Which gives me output like:

```
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: Suits
I/System.out: 2016-07-27
I/System.out: Mr. Robot
I/System.out: 2016-07-27
```

I believe that first two lines are data from deleted row. But I don't know why these data wasn't deleted completely but left with nulls. Any help?

Comment: A Java `null` and an SQL `NULL` are different things. The problem is elsewhere (in some code you have not shown).

Comment: @CL. I just got back to this and indeed you were right. I just allowed myself to add an empty object to database and did it by accident. Thanks for help.